# Rotate coordinate System of an UIView

Tags: ios

Im a complete beginner, so please excuse my maybe stupid question.

Im using an `UIView` "superview" with many children-images to perform a rotation of the images around an arbitrary point:

```
superview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

This works perfect, but it seems like this is rotating the coordinate system of the superview as well. This in turn messes up all following steps. I find hundreds of posts and infos concerning rotating images and for mac development there obviously is a method for rotating coordinate systems. I just don't find anything for iOS.

Is there a way to rotate a view without rotating the coord system / how can I rotate the coord system without influencing the images?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> it seems like this is rotating the coordinate system of the superview as well

You're right -- rotating the coordinate system of the superview is exactly what you're doing:

```
superview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

> Is there a way to rotate a view without rotating the coord system

Sure, just set the `transform` property for your view rather than for its superview. For any view `someView`, you can say:

```
someView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

Note that this actually rotates the view's own coordinate system -- it doesn't rotate the view itself. That means that all your drawing will be rotated, but the view's frame will remain the same. You might need to adjust the frame to account for this. For example, if you have a rectangular view that's normally 100px high and 300px wide, you might want to make it 300px high and 100px wide to ensure that the content is all still visible.

If you're creating a custom view, you can of course refer to instances of that view from inside its own code using `self`:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just let me maybe explain a bit closer, i somehow don't see how this is helping me at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just let me maybe explain a bit closer, i don't see how this is helping me at the moment.
Im using the superview to have a rotation of its children around an external point. So i really need the superview to rotate. I just don't want its coordinate system to rotate as well. Think of a grid of images which rotate all together (superview) and afterwards are exposed to a gravity kind of force. So i want this "gravity"/coord orientation remain the same. sorry can't vote up it says i need reputation

Comment: @user3704548 You can't have it both ways... the subviews change position *because* the coordinate system is transformed. If you want the positions of the subviews to be transformed (say, rotated right 90°) with out changing their orientation, you'll need to apply an appropriate transformation to the subviews (say, rotate left 90°).